# Nick Katz observation: "the rationality of the zeta function!"

Tags: nt.number-theory, p-adic-analysis, p-adic-numbers, weil-conjectures

In the proceedings "Algebraic Geometry - Arcata 1974" edited by R. Hartshorne there is an article by Nick Katz called "$p$-adic $L$-functions via moduli of elliptic curves". He starts by recalling $p$-adic measures. In particular, he characterizes all $p$-adic measures on $\mathbb{Z}_p$, with values in $\mathbb{Z}_p$, which correspond to rational functions in $\mathbb{Z}_p[[T-1]]$ under the Iwasawa isomorphism. Then, on page 488, he makes the following observation:

*The measures $\mu_F$ we considered above correspond exactly to the rational functions in $\mathbb{Z}_p[[T-1]]$ (the "rationality of the zeta function"!).*

Assuming he is referring to the rationality of the zeta function in the Weil conjectures, my question is:

**What is the relation between $p$-adic measures and the rationality of the zeta function of an algebraic variety over a finite field?**

The exclamation mark in his claim disturbs me. Is this something obvious?

I have studied Dwork's proof (from his paper and from Koblitz book), but I'm not familiar with Deligne et al proof of the whole conjecture.

Thank you very much.

**Edit: Apparentely, after reading the comments below, Katz is remarking here the "algebraic" construction due to Iwasawa of the $p$-adic zeta function as a quotient of power series evaluated in a power of a topological generator of a $p$-adic multiplicative group.**

Comment: EFinat-S : to answer your question about "User"'s question (now deleted by the poster) on Riemann's zeta function, it was probably downvoted because his/her question did not make any sense...

Comment: Ok, I understand. But maybe one should explain the reason. Sometimes I see downvotes in questions that after a while become excelent ones, with a lot of upvotes and feedback.

Comment: I took a look at this article by Katz, and it seems to me that he is referring to Riemann's zeta function (whence the exclamation mark).

Comment: Rationality in the sense of "rational values at negative integers"?

Comment: Here I would understand "rational" in the sense that the Iwasawa transform of $\mu^{(a)}$ is rational (as a power series).

Comment: Ok. This seems clear now. It was a simple observation about Iwasawa's construcion of $p$-adic $L$-series. Thank you very much. (Sometimes, Katz papers are extremely hard to read, since he seems to understand everything in great generality.)

Comment: Gratuitous exclamation points encourage downvotes.

Comment: @ Matt F. In the article, Katz writes this with the exclamation point. I am quoting it verbatim.

Comment: The exclamation point makes me think it is an act of humor: the algebraic gadget describing the p-adic zeta function "is" a rational function. This reminds of the Weil conjecture, of course, but is quite unrelated.

Comment: @ACL. I searched "weil conjectures" and "p-adic zeta" in MR, and found nothing. I was just hoping for some interesting relation :)

Comment: It's important to note that Iwasawa's construction of the $p$-adic zeta function was inspired partially by Weil's construction of function field zeta functions, which are rational. So ACL is not quite right to say that this is quite unrelated to the Weil conjectures - while there is no formal relation, they can be described in similar ways.

Comment: Thanks @WillSawin. I'm aware now that Iwasawa was kind of searching "similarities" between number fields and function fields over finite fields. I hope to understand this better one day. Thanks again.